# Extract Domain Name from URL using Google RE2 Regexp for Data Studio

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I have a list of URLs in an event action field, and need to extract only the domain name (without TLD) using Data studio:

```
https://example.com => example
https://www.example.com => example
https://subdomain.example.com => example
```

Managed to extract everything but the non www version with this:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Event Action, '^[^.]+.([^.]+)')
```

Any ideas how extract the non www version as well?  Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick (Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/85f0fa3b-77f1-40e8-bd89-b2c87f7fbdee) (Google Sheets Embedded) to demonstrate):

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Event Action, "(\\w+)\\.\\w+$")
```

[image: 2]]